# Which one "this"refer to?

Tags: java, android

If my class extends `Activity` and implements `SensorEventListener`, which one will `this` refer to - `Activity` or `SensorEventListener`? or Both? 
Thanks a lot.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener
```

Comment: I suggest you read about Polimorphism. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to the current instance of the class.  `implements` is for an interface so `this` can never refer to that.  You cannot create an instance of an interface, only of classes.  `Activity` is the superclass of `MainActivity` and is also not having an instance of it made.  The instance will be of `MainActivity`

However, although this is a bit pointless, you can cast `this` to all of `MainActivity`, `Activity` or `SensorEventListener` without any problems.

Comment: Thanks? why could I cast this to SensorEventListener?

Comment: You can always cast to super classes and interfaces that are implemented by your class.  So, let's say you have another class that needs a `SensorEventListener` in its constructor.  You could pass in ANY class that implements `SensorEventListener`, but the class which needs a `SensorEventListener` doesn't know that you passed in a MainActivity so it can only call the methods on that object that are in the `SensorEventListener` interface.  That's what Polymorphism is about as mentioned by @dgimenes

Comment: In fact, this is exactly what happens almost every time you need a `Context` for a View or for accessing the LayoutInflater.  You almost always pass in your Activity as the Context because Activity is a sub-sub-subclass of Context so it can be referred to as a Context

Answer (score 2):

`this` will refer to `MainActivity` that will be the instance of the class

Of course if you "change the contest" and look to an instance of `Activity`: in that case `this` could refer to `Activity` but looking to your question, the answer is definitely `MainActivity`

Answer (score 1):

`this` keyword represents current activity or class or object.

e.g.

```
private int number;

public example(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}
```

here, this.number represents private int number variable and number is methods int number.

Another example would be (its the same as in java)

```
class example implements ActionListener{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  JButton button = new JButton();
  button.addActionListener(this);
}

}
```

Since you have implemented the action listener to your class / project when you type this, it will call the action listener library.